# Switch Microsoft Word spellcheck dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

How can I change the dictionary used by Word's spellchecker to use British English instead of American English? I am using the Windows version of Word.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Word 2013: go to *Review* > *Language* > *Set Proofing Language* and pick "English (United Kingdom)". Click *Set As Default* if you want to always use that language.